# set & get values for dynamically generated select input

Tags: vue.js

I generated a few `select fields` using the code below:

```
<tr v-for="(dataPreview,index) in dataPreviewList" :key="dataPreview.headers">
    <td>{{ dataPreview.headers }}</td>
    <td>{{ dataPreview.sample }}</td>
    <td>
        <b-select :name="'selectedField' + index" v-model="systemField[index]">
            <option value="1">First Name</option>
            <option value="2">Last Name</option>
            <option value="3">Matrix Number</option>
            <option value="4">Father's Name</option>
            <option value="5">Father's ID</option>
            <option value="6">Mother's Name</option>
            <option value="7">Mother's ID</option>
            <option value="8">Contact Number</option>
        </b-select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to set the default (initial selection) for the fields, and after that how to get the selected value of all the `b-select`. What I need is, for example if `dataPreviewList` length is 7, the first b-select should have `<option value="1">First Name</option>` as the default value, the second b-select should have `<option value="2">Last Name</option>` as the default value and so on.

In my js;

```
data() {
    return {
        dataPreviewList: [],
        selectedField: [],
        systemField: []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mounted method you can loop your list and apply that logic. You'll bind it to the `systemField` for that index and set the value to the `index+1` (as it's 0-based) in this case to achieve that result.

```
mounted() {
  this.dataPreviewList.forEach((dataPreview, index) => {
    this.$set(this.systemField, index, index+1)
  })
}
```

Comment: I added your code but it doesn't seem to do anything; I've added how I declared my variables inside data return, if that may be the cause

Comment: @imin Is `dataPreviewList` populated by an axios request? If so, the code I have above must run *after* the axios call has hydrated the `dataPreviewList` variable

Comment: `this.dataPreviewList.forEach((dataPreview, index) => {
    console.log(this.systemField[index])
})` <-- for anyone else that might be looking, I use this to get the selected value for each select fields